# Two diagonal matrix in a compact form

Tags: matrices, vector

I have a 15x15 matrix which is large and impractical to format. All the elements except the main diagonal and the one under that diagonal is zero. How to format it correctly? Like I want to use two vectors instead.

Here is the matrix.

```
\begin{bmatrix}
1.4142 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-0.7071 & 1.2247 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -0.8165 & 1.1547 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -0.8660 & 1.1180 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -0.8944 & 1.0954 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.9129 & 1.0801 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.9258 & 1.0690 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.9354 & 1.0607 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.9428 & 1.0541 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.9487 & 1.0488 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.9535 & 1.0445 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.9574 & 1.0408 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.9608 & 1.0377 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.9636 & 1.0351 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.9661 & 1.0328\\
\end{bmatrix}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a vector-like expression by making a list (using the `listofitems` package) and then retrieving the elements individually.

The list are created using the  `\readlist` command.

The list is comma separated and the elements are recovered using the notation

```
\ListName[<order of the element>]
```

For convenience, two lists of 15 items were defined for this example. (Makes it easier to write the rows)

[image: a]

As a refinement, you can replace multiple zeros with a large zero.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[11pt, landscape]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{listofitems}% added <<< 
\usepackage{amsmath}% added <<<
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}% more columns allowed

\begin{document}

\small 

\readlist\DA{1.4142, 1.2247, 1.1547, 1.1180, 1.0954, 1.0801, 1.0690, 1.0607, 1.0541, 1.0488, 1.0445, 1.0408,  1.0377, 1.0351, 1.0328} % 15 elements
\readlist\DB{0, -0.7071, -0.8165, -0.8660, -0.8944, -0.9129, -0.9258, -0.9354, -0.9428, -0.9487, -0.9535, -0.9574, -0.9608, -0.9636, -0.9661}% 15 elements

$\begin{bmatrix}
    \DA[1] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \DB[2] & \DA[2] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & \DB[3] & \DA[3] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & \DB[4] & \DA[4] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 &\DB[5]& \DA[5] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \DB[6] & \DA[6] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \DB[7] & \DA[7] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \DB[8] & \DA[8] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \DB[9] & \DA[9] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \DB[10]& \DA[10] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \DB[11] & \DA[11] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \DB[12] & \DA[12] & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \DB[13] & \DA[13] & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \DB[14] & \DA[14] & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \DB[15] &\DA[15]
\end{bmatrix}$

\newpage

$\begin{bmatrix}
    \DA[1] &&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
    \DB[2] & \DA[2] &&&&&&&&&&&&& \\
    & \DB[3] & \DA[3] &&&&&&&&&&&&\\
    && \DB[4] & \DA[4] &&&&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&\DB[5]& \DA[5] &&&&&\makebox(0,0){\text{\Huge0}}&&&&&\\
    &&&& \DB[6] & \DA[6] &&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&& \DB[7] & \DA[7] &&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&& \DB[8] & \DA[8] &&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&& \DB[9] & \DA[9] &&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&& \DB[10]& \DA[10] &&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&& \DB[11] & \DA[11] &&&&\\
    &&&\makebox(0,0){\text{\Huge0}}&&&&&&& \DB[12] & \DA[12] &&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&& \DB[13] & \DA[13] &&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&& \DB[14] & \DA[14] &\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&&& \DB[15] &\DA[15]
\end{bmatrix}$
        
\end{document}
```

The final example shows the `pmatrix` using the `nicematrix` package and using horizontal, vertical and diagonal dotted lines: `\Cdots`, `\Vdots` and `\Ddots`. (It will compile twice)

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[11pt, landscape]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{listofitems}% added <<<<< 
\usepackage{nicematrix}% added <<<<<
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}% more columns allowed
 
\begin{document}
    
\small 
    
\readlist\DA{1.4142, 1.2247, 1.1547, 1.1180, 1.0954, 1.0801, 1.0690, 1.0607, 1.0541, 1.0488, 1.0445, 1.0408,  1.0377, 1.0351, 1.0328} % 15 elements
\readlist\DB{0, -0.7071, -0.8165, -0.8660, -0.8944, -0.9129, -0.9258, -0.9354, -0.9428, -0.9487, -0.9535, -0.9574, -0.9608, -0.9636, -0.9661}% 15 elements
    
$\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.5ex} % expand the rows
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[xdots/shorten=1em] % make line dots with shorter length
    \DA[1] & 0 & \Cdots &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0 \\
    \DB[2] &\DA[2] & \Ddots &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & & \Vdots\\
    0 & \DB[3] &\DA[3] &  &  &  & &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
    \Vdots & \Ddots & \DB[4]& \DA[4] &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
    &  &  & \DB[5] &\DA[5] &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
    &  &  &  & \DB[6] & \DA[6] &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
    &  &  &  &  & \DB[7] &\DA[7] &  & &  &  &  &  &  & \\
    &  &  &  &  &  & \DB[8] & \DA[8] &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
    &  &  &  &  &  &  & \DB[9] &\DA[9] &  &  &  &  &  & \\
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \DB[10] & \DA[10] &  &  & &  & \\
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \DB[11] &\DA[11] &  &  &  & \\
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \DB[12] & \DA[12] &  &  & \\
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \DB[13] &\DA[13] &  & \\
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \DB[14] & \DA[14] & 0\\
    0 & \Cdots  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0 & \DB[15] &\DA[15]
    \end{bNiceMatrix}$
    
\end{document}
```

**Note.** The elements of the lists created here has, for clarity,  a leading space, which is irrelevant in a tabular environment. To suppress such space use `\readlist*`.